Generated pressure when two water interfaces collide
Background
I'm studying a bulk cavitaion problem as described in V. J. Cushing - On the theory of bulk cavitation. In the problem an incident shock wave (from the water $z < 0$) is reflected as a tensile wave from the free interface ($z = 0$). The interaction of the incident shock and tensile reflection causes a region of negative pressure in the water. It is assumed that as the pressure becomes negative the water cavitates immediately, we then end up with a region of cavitated water as illustrated by the dashed line in the figure below

The pressure difference between the uncavitated and cavitated water results in that the cavitation region will collapse. As the region claps together a pressure, which is called the water hammer pressure in the literature, is generated. It is often stated without proof that the resulting water hammer pressure is given by
\begin{equation}
P = \frac{1}{2} \rho c \left(V_L - V_U\right)
\end{equation}
where $\rho$ and $c$ are the waters density and speed of sound respectively. The velocities $V_L$ and $V_U$ are the velocities of the upper and lower interface right before closure.
A more general version of the formula is given in E. Johnsen and T. Colonius - Numerical simulations of non-spherical bubble collapse:
\begin{equation}
P =  \rho_L c_L v_j \frac{\rho_S c_S}{\rho_S c_S + \rho_L c_L}.
\end{equation}
Here $v_j$ is the water-jet velocity which impacts a solid of impdance $\rho_S c_S$. The impedance of the jet is $\rho_L c_L$. The expression reduces to the above when we set the impedances equal to each other $\rho_S c_S = \rho_L c_L = \rho c$.
Question
However, remembering the well known problem where we apply Bernoullis equation to a water jet which impacts a rigid wall (as discussed here) the pressure at the stagnation point is $P_0 + 1/2 \rho V_0^2$, where $V_0$ is the impact velocity. The expressions for the water hammer and stagnation pressure are very similar except for the speed of sound factor.
My question then reduces to: if we have two interfaces of water with density $\rho$ and speed of sound $c$ that collides with velocities $V_U$ and $V_L$, what is the pressure generated at the collision point? Or equivalently how can we derive the equation
\begin{equation}
P =  \rho_L c_L v_j \frac{\rho_S c_S}{\rho_S c_S + \rho_L c_L}?
\end{equation}

anything I can do to make the question more accessible?
